# Spring Boot Application not configuring datasource through CircleCi

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, circleci

I have a Spring Boot Rest Api (v2.2.6.RELEASE) with a mysql database

When I ssh into the remote box and run `java -jar` it builds and runs perfectly but when I run that same command through CircleCi I get the following.

```
2021-12-25 17:53:30.112 ERROR 30084 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Below is an extract of the properties file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=****
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Also, Im using the same user for both CircleCi and when I ssh and deploy manually.

Any help and guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your spring boot application assumes mysql database running, which apparently is not running in the CircleCI context - hence the run fails.

Comment: It assumes it is running. and it is indeed running. All CircleCi is doing is ssh'ing into the box and running a command. How would any context of CircleCi affect whats happening in the remote server? 
Whats the difference between writing a workflow to ssh and run a command and actually ssh'ing and running that same command?

Comment: The error explicitly says that database url is not set correctly. So start debugging from there. Regarding the ssh part that's a significant detail missing from your question.